# How to query datetime fields between date range, and also within those dates between times in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I need to generate a report using data that has a field called "CreatedDate". This field is a date and timestamp. I need to create a query that does something like select all rows where CreatedDate is from '01/01/2018' to '06/02/2018' AND within those date ranges only where time is between '13:30:00' to '18:00:00'. I am having issues trying to accomplish this.

Below is an example of what i tried:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM [tablename]
WHERE [CreatedBy] = '792'
      AND ([CreatedDate] >= '2018-01-01'
           OR [CreatedDate] <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
      AND ([CreatedDate] BETWEEN '13:30:00' AND '16:00:00')
ORDER BY 
    [ID] DESC;
```

Now this is not working, but not sure how to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. -Thanks-

Comment: Microsoft SQL just plain query. Not using report builder or anything like that. Not using MySQL, just Microsoft SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this`select * from [tablename] 
where CreatedBy = '792' 
and (CreatedDate >= '2018-01-01' or CreatedDate <= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) AND 
(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CreatedDate ,108) BETWEEN '13:30:00' AND '16:00:00' ORDER BY ID desc`

Comment: this worked, but for anyone using this in future be sure to add extra ')' after '16:00:00' to encapsulate it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the [TIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function.

```
select * from [tablename] 
where CreatedBy = '792' 
and (CreatedDate >= '2018-01-01' or CreatedDate <= CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)) AND 
(TIME(CreatedDate) BETWEEN TIME('13:30:00') AND TIME('16:00:00')) ORDER BY ID desc
```

Comment: What are you using to execute your queries

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the:

```
(CreatedDate BETWEEN '13:30:00' AND '16:00:00') ORDER BY ID desc
```

Is the part that isn't working - You could try:

```
and (DATEPART(Hour, CreatedDate) between 12.5 and 15
```